# Python 2.7.2 shelve fails on OSX

Tags: python, shelve

Using the shelve standard lib on Python 2.7.2, I wrote an extremely simple test to create a persistent data file and then immediately open it for printing:

```
import os
import shelve

shelf_filename = str(__file__.split('.')[0] + '.dat')

#delete the shelf file if it exists already.
try:
    os.remove(shelf_filename)
    print "DELETED LEFTOVER SHELF FILE", shelf_filename
except OSError:
    pass

#create a new shelf, write some data, and flush it to disk
shelf_handle = shelve.open(shelf_filename)
print "OPENED", shelf_filename, "WITH SHELF"
shelf_handle['foo'] = 'bar'
shelf_handle.close()
print "FLUSHED AND CLOSED THE SHELF"

#re-open the shelf we just wrote, read/print the data, and close it
shelf_handle = shelve.open(shelf_filename)
print "RE-OPENED", shelf_filename, "WITH SHELF"
print 'foo:', shelf_handle.get('foo')
shelf_handle.close()

#delete the shelf file
os.remove(shelf_filename)
```

However this script fails unexpectedly when it tries to re-open the shelf it just created:

```
DELETED LEFTOVER SHELF FILE shelve_test.dat
OPENED shelve_test.dat WITH SHELF
FLUSHED AND CLOSED THE SHELF
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shelve_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    shelf_handle = shelve.open(shelf_filename)
  File ".../shelve.py", line 239, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File ".../shelve.py", line 223, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, anydbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File ".../anydbm.py", line 82, in open
    raise error, "db type could not be determined"
anydbm.error: db type could not be determined
```

This is about the most basic possible usage of shelve so I really don't understand what I'm missing, and AFAIK I'm following the docs to the letter. Can somebody with a little shelve experience please tell me what's going on?

UPDATE: This script apparently works in certain platforms and not others, which is really kind of surprising for a Python standard lib. Definitely confirmed this does NOT work on:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, May 15 2013, 13:46:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
```

Comment: your code worked as is for me,  what versions of everything are you running?

edit: I also don't understand why you would use shelves just to delete them.

Comment: hooo boy...that's really bad for a standard lib. Added my OS and Python version details to the original question. What are your version details?

Comment: Re deleting shelves: This is just for the example, to make it really clear that shelve was creating the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of Python shelve is using a deprecated dbm package, and the issue can be solved by specifying a different dbm as follows:

```
import anydbm
anydbm._defaultmod = __import__('dumbdbm')
```

If those two lines are added to the script above then everything works as expected. This really needs to be fixed in shelve.

Comment: Is possible to fix without modifying the script?

Answer (score 1):

`shelve` doesn't expect you to specify the extension on the filename.  Instead it gives the file an extension based on which db was used to create the file.

So when you call `shelve.open("shelve_test.dat")`, you are creating a file that `shelve` expects to be created in using `dumbdbm`, but is instead created with a different (better) database manager.

Instead, you should be calling `shelve.open("shelve_test")`, that way `shelve` can choose to save the file using the correct extension.  This also applies when opening an already created file.

Comment: P.S.: For the record, `dumbdbm` is the least efficient db. Whatever your computer uses by default is probably going to be the most efficient one it has.