# shelve is not able to open a file just created

Tags: python, python-2.5

with python25 I'm having an issue with shelve. I'm trying a very basic example:

```
>>> info_file = shelve.open('test')
>>> info_file['test'] ='hello'
>>> info_file.close()

>>> info_file = shelve.open('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/shelve.py", line 225, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/shelve.py", line 209, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, anydbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/anydbm.py", line 80, in open
    raise error, "db type could not be determined"
anydbm.error: db type could not be determined
```

It works on a Debian environment. but not on my MACOSX

I've read here:

http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/13922

that it could be because i've no DB handlers, but how i can install a db handler (probably with pip) and which db handler should I install

Comment: Try `info_file.close()`

Comment: this works perfectly on a ubuntu environment, but on my macOSX is not working

Comment: thanks, I was using close() but it dont work, updated question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949832/python-2-7-2-shelve-fails-on-osx Any use?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this error is:

```
import anydbm
anydbm._defaultmod = __import__('dumbdbm')
```